# Rotating a UIButton?

Tags: xcode, swift, rotation, uibutton

I am trying to rotate a UIButton so it looks more like a diamond instead of a square. I have searched a lot on the site and could not find anything that could help me. I am having a lot of trouble with this and need some help. I think it will increase the appeal of my app when it is running. This is a problem I have had for a while and have been struggling with so anything can help me. I don't know if this is a built in feature in Xcode or if I need to do this programmatically.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply apply an affine transform to the button. Something like this:

```
import Darwin

...

myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)
```

However, that will rotate the entire button, including the title. If that's not what you want then it gets more complicated.

Comment: I would preferably like the title to stay the same and the button to rotate

Comment: The title is part of the button. The simplest thing to do if you want an unusual shaped button with a normal title  is to make it type "custom" in IB and add a background image. That's trivially easy to do.